# Are combinatorial problems inherently NP-Complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Most combinatorial problems seem NP-complete. Is this inherent in the design of the problems themselves? Are there any combinatorial problems in "P" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "combinatorial problem"? There are plenty of problems in P and many of them, such as finding matchings, have a very combinatorial flavour.

Answer (score 8):

No. Counterexamples (problems in $P$) include shortest path, max flow, minimum spanning tree,...

Comment: There are also plenty of examples that are not in NP. (For your list, also sorting.)

Answer (score 5):

The "P" part of "NP" refers to the time on a nondeterministic TM being polynomial *in the size of the representation of the input*. This is an important point which sometimes gets lost when thinking about complexity theory.

One interesting consequence of this definition is that you can sometimes construct a problem in a higher complexity class by using a representation which is smaller.

Take any NP-complete problem using a "natural" representation, such as Hamiltonian circuit on a graph represented as an adjacency matrix. Note that the size of the representation of the graph is polynomial in $|V|$. Now let's suppose there is a compressed representation (e.g. a succinct circuit; I'll give a reference at the end) of the graph which is polylogarithmic in $|V|$, that is, a polynomial in $\log |V|$.

The compressed representation of the graph is exponentially smaller than the uncompressed representation. So any algorithm which solves the original problem on *this* input is exponentially more complex than an algorithm which solves the problem on the uncompressed representation! Specifically, the new problem is now NEXPTIME-complete which, by the time hierarchy theorem, is not in NP.

So to answer your question, no, combinatorial problems are not inherently NP-complete, because changing the representation of the input may change the complexity class of the problem. But in another sense they might be, because for a large class of problems, you may be able to choose a representation of the input which makes the problem NP-complete.

For more on succinct graphs and complexity theory: Galperin, [*Succinct Representations of Graphs*](https://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/temp/RandomHardProblems/Succinct%20Representations%20of%20Graphs/Succinct%20Representations%20of%20Graphs%20.pdf), Information and Control, 56:183-198 (1983).